# SQL- LIKE search with List of values

Tags: sql

I have list of values which needs to be like searched.

```
select * 
from table 
where fname in ('%abc%','%nnn%') or 
      lname in ('%abc%','%nnn%')
```

what will be best way? I know We cant use "LIKE" and "IN" together.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE fname LIKE '%abc%' OR fname LIKE '%nnn%' OR lname LIKE '%abc%' OR lname LIKE '%nnn%'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also a good approach, if you accept,

```
select * 
from table 
where 
fname in (select fname from table where fname like '%abc%' or fname like '%nnn%') or 
lname in (select lname from table where lname like '%abc%' or lname like '%nnn%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use several LIKE predicates combined with OR or you can check if your database system provides a REGEX function.

Comment: It supports but how to use that?

Comment: Since your rquirements are still simple, use LIKE. You will know that you should learn regular expressions when the time comes.